# Compare files between two branches in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I know how to do this in SVN,

```
svn diff http://svn.example.com/branches/A/File1.txt http://svn.example.com/branches/B/File1.txt
```

But there has to be a less painful way to do this in TortoiseSVN. You would think that you could do it from the Show Log, but it appears to only show revisions on the current branch.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

1. Go to the repository browser (<right click>/TortoiseSVN/Repo-browser/<enter URL>).
2. Open right click menu on branch B, select 'Mark for comparison'.
3. Then open right click menu on branch A, select 'Compare URLs' or 'Show differences as unified diff'.

Comment: I think this works well across all versions, but in more recent versions, you should use the shortcut mentioned by Kris Erickson in his answer below.

Comment: This approach ignores local changes whereas the approach in Kris Ericksons answers includes local changes. Both have their use cases. Imho just something one should be aware of.

Answer (score 70):

I don't know how new this feature is (I certainly read the documentation and didn't find it when I posted the question), but if you hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button down when you right click on a file, you can compare URLs without having to go to the repository browser.

See Difference to another branch/tag in the [Viewing Differences](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html) documentation.

To illustrate:

[image]

Comment: This works fine in TortoiseSVN 1.6.12 (corresponding to SVN 1.6.15), 2010-11-24.

Comment: this more appropriately answers the question of comparing files without the need to open the repo browser.  Love it.  Thanks a ton!  There are a few other goodies that show up in the SHIFT + Right Click and view the TortoiseSVN menu.

Comment: Directories can also be compared likewise. Tortoise 1.6.7 - works like a charm.

Answer (score 24):

I find this method to be much easier:

Open the revision graph for the file you want to diff (`context menu->TortoiseSVN->Revision Graph`).  Select the first revision, and then control-click to select the second revision.  Now right click on one of the selected revisions, and select `Compare Revisions` from the context menu.

Tested on TortoiseSVN 1.7.6.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are cool, i love it! Another **cool** way to diff, in my case, 2 *different* files found in 2 *different* folders:

## Step 1 - Right-click, Diff later

[image]

## Step 2 - Right-click, Diff with "..."

[image]

That's it! :)