# How do I compare a branch against trunk in subversion?

Tags: svn

In Subversion, I created a branch from a trunk using `svn copy`. According to the the [SVN 1.5 manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html), "This is the easiest way to “tag” a revision in your repository—just svn copy that revision (usually HEAD) into your tags directory."

```
svn copy file:////svn/projectX/trunk file:///svn/projectX/branches/stefanl
```

Then, I make my modifications to the `stefanl` branch. I want to commit my changes to the trunk, but before I do that I would like to see a diff of the changes.

How can I diff the 'stefanl' branch against the 'trunk' branch? I tried `svn diff`, but it didn't provide much information:

```
% svn diff file:////svn/projectX/trunk file:///svn/projectX/branches/stefanl
Property changes on: .
___________________________________________________________________
Modified: svn:mergeinfo
   Reverse-merged /trunk:r1699-1870
```

Comment: That should work. Have you definitely committed your changes to your branch? Are you asking if you can diff your working copy against a different branch?

Comment: @Rup: I committed my changes to the 'stefanl' branch. Now I want to merge the 'stefanl' branch into the trunk. But before I do that, I want to preview the changes. I thought `svn diff` would show all of the differences between the trunk and my branch, but it does not.

Comment: @Stevan: `svn diff` *does* show the differences between branches when used like that. The fact that it doesn't show you any means there aren't any. Examine the output of `svn log -v file:///svn/projectX` to see what happened, specifically to see in which branch you committed the changes you expected to see.

Comment: I am new to SVN after several years of git+github and I must say that simple, fast everyday features suddenly are quite complicated!

Answer (score 70):

Adding to the previous answers (if using Tortoise SVN on Windows):

- Right-click any folder. From the context menu, select **TortoiseSVN** -> **Repo-browser**.
- Enter your repo address in the **URL** box.
- Navigate to the first folder which you want to compare. Right-click and select **Mark for comparison**.
- Navigate to the second folder. Right-click and select **Compare URLs**

Comment: The question did not mention Tortoise SVN or Windows, so an answer using the SVN command line would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks Treb. That was a helpful addition to the conversation.

Comment: See a Tortoise SVN answer with a few more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8822244/4178262

Answer (score 9):

You can Unix diff to compare directories.

To find missing files:

```
diff -r svn/projectX/trunk svn/projectX/branches/stefanl | grep -i only
```

To find what the differences between files:

```
diff -ru svn/projectX/trunk svn/projectX/branches/stefanl
```

I had the same question and found the suggestion in a mail thread:
http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2003-08/0538.shtml

Comment: Yes, this one.  The key thing that was missing in the initial question was the '-r' (recursive) flag.  The 'u' flag in the second example shown here simply changes the type of diff output.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
 svn diff ^/trunkUrl/fileName ^/branchUrl/fileName
```

This will give you the difference between a file in branch and trunk.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the other answers and a little research, I wrote a script that does it automatically.

```
#!/bin/bash
url=$(svn info | grep ^URL: | sed -e 's,^URL: ,,' )
root=$(svn info | grep '^Repository Root:' | sed -e 's,.*Root: ,,' )
trunk=$root/trunk
if [[ -n "$1" && ! -e "$1" ]]
then
    echo "What? svn diff \"$1\"? really?"
    exit
fi
svn diff $url/$1 $trunk/$1 > trunk.diff
```

You run it just under the branch. You can pass a path (dir or file) and it will work as expected. If not then it will just diff the branch and the trunk.

Comment: Using XML makes it much more reliable: `svninfo () { svn info --xml | xmllint --xpath "$1"'/text()' - ; }`

Comment: This is good if the branch was created from the root of the repository. If the branch was created from a subdirectory, this won't work. So you may want to modify the script to take 2 arguments and to duplicate the first argument if only one is provided.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the info guys, I would add something to improve the readability of the diff results.If you used:
 svn diff svn://url:9090/branches/PRD_0002 svn://url:9090/branches/TST_0003 >svn_diff_filename.txt

You can also use: 
findstr "Index:" C:\path\svn_diff_filename.txt >svn_diff_file_list.txt

That will bring you a readable list of files that have any differences.

Regards, 
Kra.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Subversive plugin with eclipse(other ide's ?) switch to the repository browsing perspective.
In the SVN Repositories panel just right click on any item and select the "Compare..." option.
It should be intuitive from there.