# Tortoise SVN: compare two directories (instead of files or revisions)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, compare, code-duplication

You can compare two revisions or files with Tortoise SVN. Is there also a way to compare two directories?

I have two directories containing source code. 90 percent of the code is identical. Now I'm going to store identical code in a plugin since duplicate code is bad. Tortoise Diff would be perfect for this if there was a way to compare two directories.

How can I achieve this?
If it isn't possible with Tortoise, do you have other ideas / tools in mind for this purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two source trees for differences/changes on win32?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204818/how-to-compare-two-source-trees-for-differences-changes-on-win32)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure about Tortoise, but if you're running Windows I recommend WinMerge.

http://winmerge.org/

Comment: It's not particularly pretty, but it does function well. As I'm sure the rest of our community does, I thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 5):

Right click the "Folder" which you want to compare
Select "Mark for Comparison" 
Right click the other folder which you want to compare 
Select "Compare URLs" 
it will list out all the changes 
You can select them and copy them to local or copy them to another svn folder.

Hope this helps..

Comment: yeah, winmerge allows this (as recommended in the accepted answer). But I would be surprised if this was possible with tortoise-svn.

Comment: Yes. It is in built SVN functionality. I am using it on day to day basis. Let me know if you need more help on this

Comment: This answer works but only applies to the repository folders (via repo-browser). See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4677731/362298

Answer (score 2):

[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) is an excellent diff tool which supports directory comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Araxis Merge or WinMerge for this. They should allow you to set filters so that you can ignore .svn folder during comparison.

Answer (score 1):

treecomp, for win only though :( but it's free